# read streaming videos from Android code

Tags: android, streaming

After many research on the net, i'm obliged to ask you about **Streaming on Android**, how can I **read streaming by specifying URL** or at least how to **integrate youtube videos** on my **android application**? Thanks a lot

Comment: you can do pseudo streaming by using a basic videoview and giving it a simple http url. you only need to have streamable videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this library http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/

The use of the library is very easy.

code example:

```
Intent lVideoIntent = new Intent(null, Uri.parse("ytpl://"+YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_ID), this, OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.class);
startActivity(lVideoIntent);
```

[The YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#data_api) allows a program to perform many of the operations available on the YouTube.